# What research articles were inspired by web comics?

Tags: reference-request, big-list

Currently, I'm doing a PhD on the applications of algorithms to generate timelines of textual content. Recently, I found an article entitled *StoryFlow: Tracking the Evolution of Stories* by S. Liu et al. (2013), which can be found over [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6634164?casa_token=5vFDmkpYFyMAAAAA:8X6OypnPb0C5XYBEmXoXywJJWVObvj4JA28ZhDGl526IsZMGKG0dJkwEh5guS_TaPK2XNrUD).

The article presents a computational method through which the location of different characters relative to one another throughout time is visually presented. What I found remarkable, whas that on p. 2442 it explicitly mentions and compares the outcome of the algorithm with the Jurassic Park panel of the 657'th XKCD [comic](https://xkcd.com/657/) "Movie Narrative Charts".

Here is the comparison in the article:

[image]

Another, more recent article that was inspired by this particular comic by Munroe is named *HyperStorylines: Interactively Untangling Dynamic hypergraphs*. It was published in 2022 and can be found [over here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/14738716211045007) (PDF).

In general, I often find the work of Randall Munroe funny and interesting at the same time, and can imagine it has served as inspiration for scientific work more often.

Yet more generally, I wonder which scientific articles were in some way inspired by web comics. I know quite a few inventions of the past have built on the imaginative comic *books* (see e.g. the following [list](https://www.storypick.com/comic-book-inventions/)). I restrict this question to web comics because they've been made more recently, and I haven't seen any of them mentioned in lists of the type mentioned above. I'm interested in both research articles and inventions that have come about at least in part thanks to the existence of a particular web comic.

**Question**: what research articles and inventions were inspired by web comics?

Comment: Your first link is broken. While I don't have references wrt to your specific question about web comics, with your permission, I do have a few digressive comments. The canonical use of *storyline graphs* is probably Minard's 1869 visualization of Napoleon's Russian invasion and retreat, updated in Tufte https://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/posters This genre of visuals are also known as *river networks* as utilized in this paper on topic networks for the annual SOTU https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1512221112 Finally,  https://www.animemangastudies.com  FWIW

Comment: @DJohnson Fixed the broken link, thank you for pointing it out. Will look into the pointers you've provided - thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If we ignore research on webcomics themselves, [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/) seems to be the most common webcomic inspiration for science and mathematical research, and these are pretty much all in computer science and visualization.

Searching for "xkcd" on Google Scholar [turns up thousands of results](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22xkcd%22&oq=), and although most of these are either acknowledgements of use of images or to the use the [xkcd-style plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12675147/1598769) you mention, xkcd has inspired some other research, e.g.

- ["High Level Internet Scale Traffic Visualization Using Hilbert Curve Mapping."](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-78243-8_10) (2007), inspired by [xkcd-195 "Map of the Internet"](https://xkcd.com/195/).)
- ["Failure is a Four-Letter Word"](https://thomas-zimmermann.com/publications/files/zeller-promise-2011.pdf)  (2011), inspired by [xkcd-936 "Significant"](http://xkcd.com/882/).
- ["Correct horse battery staple: Exploring the usability of system-assigned passphrases."](https://doi.org/10.1145/2335356.2335366) (2012), inspired by [xkcd-936 "Password Strength"](https://xkcd.com/936/).
- ["How to memorize a random 60-bit string"](https://aclanthology.org/N15-1180.pdf) (2015), inspired by [xkcd-936 "Password Strength"](https://xkcd.com/936/).
- ["Stippling of 2D Scalar Fields"](https://doi.org/10.1109/TVCG.2019.2903945) (2019), inspired by [xkcd-1939 "2016 Election Map"](https://xkcd.com/1939/).
- ["The Nebraska Problem in Open Source Software Development"](https://doi.org/10.7880/abas.0220914a) (2022), inspired by [xkcd-2347 "Dependency"](https://xkcd.com/2347/).

I can't immediately find similar inspiration acknowledgements for other "scientific" web comics such as [PHD Comics](https://phdcomics.com/comics.php), [Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal](http://www.smbc-comics.com/), [Dinosaur Comics](https://qwantz.com/index.php), and [Abstruse Goose](https://abstrusegoose.com/).

It is, of course, a problem that researchers are not always consciously aware of the sources of their inspiration. Even if they are aware that a webcomic inspired them, they may be embarrassed to admit it in a published paper.

Comment: Thank you for your well-researched answer! It's amazing how many researchers have been inspired by xkcd. Hope scientific articles based on web comics made by people besides Randall Munroe will one day be written as well.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, David, that I edited xkcd's wiki article - particularly the "Inspired Activities" section - so make it include a subsection on "Academic Research". It includes references to articles found by both of us. I've notified Randall Munroe's team about this as well